# How can I create a list with a changing variable?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm creating a python program to output the aliquot sequence depending on the input. The basis of my code works, however, I want to change the format of the result into a list.

I've tried appending to a list, returning values but, because of how the code is set up to iterate, I can't print the value of the variable in turn; it all gets printed at once.

```py
def result(total):    
    print(total) 

def AliquotSequence(userInput):
    global total
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, (userInput//2) + 1):
        if userInput % i == 0:
            total += i

    result(total)

    if total == 1:
        print('Finished!')
    else:
        AliquotSequence(total)

userInput = int(input('Number: ')) 
AliquotSequence(userInput)
```

I expect the output, in the code provided, to be (when inputting 20):

```
22
14
10
8
7
1
Finished!
```

This is correct, however, when I try and put this data into a list, I get:

```
[22]
[14]
[10]
[8]
[7]
[1]
Finished!
```

How would I achieve the output of 
`[22, 14, 10, 8, 7, 1]`?
Thank you.

Comment: why did you create a wrapper function for print?

Comment: create a `my_list` and replace `result(total)` with `my_list.append(total)`, finally print the list after `AliquotSequence(userInput)`.

Comment: @ZacharyOldham That is where I was going to implement the code for a list

Comment: @AniketSahrawat  Where should I create a `my_list` as it says that it isn't defined in the error code. Thank you for your help in advance. After creating a global variable, I no longer received the error message however the output is just `[1]`

Comment: @Arctic See answer by Austin

Comment: @Arctic just look at my answer below. I am explaining exactly how to do that

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Yes sorry, it's solved now so thank you. The responses just came so quick that I couldn't follow all of it!

Comment: @Arctic But you decided to remove my answer as the accepted one.. ok..

Comment: @Akaisteph7 If you couldn't already tell, I'm obviously new to this so I tried to accept two answers as I deemed them both as helpful and correct. However, I've now realized that you can't do that, so you'll just have to accept my appreciation in the good old comment form :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a keyword parameter to function and pass the `result` in every recursive call:

```
def AliquotSequence(userInput, result=[]):
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, (userInput//2) + 1):
        if userInput % i == 0:
            total += i

    result.append(total)

    if total == 1:
        print(result)
        print('Finished!')
    else:
        AliquotSequence(total, result)
```

Note that using `global` in any language normally is a bad design and I don't believe you need a function just to print value.

Comment: btw, you don't need to pass the result to `AliquotSequence` in else part ;)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat you def do need to.

Comment: It would work without passing it. Just replace `else:
        AliquotSequence(total, result)` with `else:
        AliquotSequence(total)` and see. @Akaisteph7

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I guess if you use `AliquotSequence(userInput)` and not `AliquotSequence(userInput, res)` like i was it would work yes. But then you lose the list, which is fine in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list to your recursive function to do this. As long as you keep passing the same list back to your function, it will get updated properly and you can just print it once at the end of the recursion:

```
def AliquotSequence(userInput, res):
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, (userInput//2) + 1):
        if userInput % i == 0:
            total += i

    res.append(total)
    if total == 1:
        print(res)
        print('Finished!')
    else:
        AliquotSequence(total, res)

res = []
userInput = int(input('Number: ')) 
AliquotSequence(userInput, res)
```

Output

```
[22, 14, 10, 8, 7, 1]                                                                                                                                                              
Finished!
```